# Write file to a subdirectory node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with node and express and i have a directory structure like

```
public
   img
   css
   js
server.js
```

in server.js i have the following code for writing to a png file

```
fs.writeFile('testfile.png', imageData, function(err){

        res.send("file successfully created");

    });
```

this creates the file in the root i.e. with the following directory structure

```
public
   img
   css
   js
server.js
testfile.png
```

How do I create `testfile.png`inside the `img` directory? simply using `img/testfile.png`, `/img/testfile.png` or `/public/img/testfile.png` does not work-- no file is created.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this

`'./public/img/testfile.png'`

Or, you can give relative path like this

`__dirname + '/public/img/testfile.png'`

Also check for the permission of the directory `img`. May be the write permission is not given.

Comment: does the first one work? img is under public not the current directory?

Comment: Oops. forgot to add `public`, edited.. did you check permissions?

Comment: ok that works...although i just realized i was not restarting the node server!..that probably has more to do with my issues :) will accept your answer though. Thanks!

Comment: How do you do this with ecmascript modules, in a way that [ESLINT won't complain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337576/)?