# ESlint - import.meta causes Fatal Parsing Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, atom-editor, eslint, es6-modules

Using the [Atom](https://atom.io/) editor, with the [linter-eslint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint) package installed, I have a node.mjs script that uses ES6 module's [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statement to import various node modules.

The script runs fine when I run it with node's [--experimental-modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) flag. However, while editing with Atom, linter-eslint says:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token import (Fatal)
```

This parsing error is **NOT** being caused by the ecmascript "import" statements that I have at the top of my code file. Instead, it is actually caused by the fact that eslint considers "import" a reserved token that can only be used in [import statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and therefore cannot be used by the [import.meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta) object (as shown in this code line below):

```
const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
```

My .eslintrc.js file has these parser options:

```
'parserOptions':
{
    'ecmaVersion': 2018,
    'sourceType': 'module'
}
```

How can I configure eslint to ignore this particular error?

Comment: @LonnieBest Did you try the `"parser": "babel-eslint"` eslint config as in the linked issue?

Comment: @Bergi : I did; it lead to another [issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11189#issuecomment-457303090).

Comment: @LonnieBest You would of course have to pass all 4 options to the `parserOptions`.

Comment: @Bergi : I think you've discovered my issue. I'm setting the parser with `eslint.parserOptions.parser = 'babel-eslint'`. However, I should be setting it how you said: `eslint.parser = 'babel-eslint'`. These properties are of the main eslint object; they're NOT properties of the `parserOptions` object.

Comment: [ES Lint Bug 13133](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/13133)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just came across this issue too.  Support for `import.meta` was added in [eslint 7.2.0](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/13196#issuecomment-643518200) (June 2020) however in order to make it work I had to edit `.eslintrc.json` and change `ecmaVersion` from `2018` to `2020`.

Answer (score 9):

@Malvineous's answer worked for me, but I was unsure of where to put the `emcaVersion` value in the `.eslintrc` file.

It should go in the top level of the JSON object in the `.eslintrc` file.

```
{ 
    "rules": { ... }, 
    "parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 2020 }, 
    "settings": { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sure the is not the best solution but I did this...

First create another file (I used Util.mjs) and move the logic into that...

```
import path from 'path';
const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
export { __dirname }
```

Then create `.eslintignore` and add `{path}/Util.mjs`. Finally use the new import in your original class...

```
import {__dirname} from './Util.mjs';
```