# Why is linting failing with "Unexpected token ." on "import.meta.url"?

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have the following lint config...

```
{
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "google"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {
    "require-jsdoc": 1
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true
  }
}
```

and the following code...

```
const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
                                           //^Error is...
```

But when it lints I get...

```
9:46  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token .
```

This is a pretty common piece of code so I am confused.

**Update**

solved with...

```
"ignorePatterns": ["unclean.mjs", "node_modules"],
```

But I would like a solution where I don't have to ignore an entire file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ESlint - import.meta causes Fatal Parsing Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54337576/eslint-import-meta-causes-fatal-parsing-error). You'll want to use `babel-eslint`.

Comment: That is basically what I did but I don't feel like it is a legitimate answer. Thank you for finding that!

Comment: Oh! I didn't even notice that the original answer was actually from you! I just gave it a try and setting `"parser": "babel-eslint"` and `"env": { "node": true }` worked for me. Let me know if that works for you too, I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Ah, and you'll need to `npm i -D babel-eslint`

Comment: Thanks but babel is not an option in my case

Answer (score 4):

It is a syntax error because the default parser of ESLint only supports stage 4 proposals, but [import.meta](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta) is currently stage 3. For now, you must change the parser to "babel-eslint" or "@typescript-eslint/parser" in order to parse `import.meta`.

That phrase is a syntax error because `import` is a keyword in EcmaScript. Therefore `import.meta` is as invalid as `if.foo` or `switch.foo`.